# Ansible: how to get values in array use in when condition

Tags: ansible

I have variable in role

```
component: [ mouse, keyboard, cpu ]
```

in my role i need to import task according to the component variable

```
- import_tasks: cpu.yml
  when: '"cpu" in component'
```

this work if there is only one value in component, how can i loop over the component var and use it in when condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the use-case. Do you want to loop all items?

```
vars:
  component: [ mouse, keyboard, cpu ]
tasks:
  - import_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
    loop: component
```

Or, do you want to import only selected components?

```
vars:
  component: [ mouse, keyboard, cpu ]
  selected: [ mouse, cpu ]
tasks:
  - import_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
    loop: selected
    when: item in component
```

(not tested)